# having error with from decouple import config

Tags: python

I cannot from decouple import config.
I tried uninstalling decouple and reinstalling it, but it is still telling import error cannot import config from decouple.

Comment: Check if Python/pip `--version` you used for installing is same you used for running shell or script.

Comment: It is possible that you're using a virtual environment, in which case make sure you target the correct python interpreter when installing your package so that it is available to import.